# How to edit java.util.package

Tags: java, package

I have a class that contains some useful methods.This is the code for that:

```
import java.util.Vector;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class bk {
    private static int iAsLoopRunner=0;
    static Scanner takeInput=new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void print_int(int arr[])
    {
        for(iAsLoopRunner=0;iAsLoopRunner<arr.length;iAsLoopRunner++)
        {
            System.out.print(arr[iAsLoopRunner]+" "+"|"+" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    public static void print_float(float arr[])
    {
        for(iAsLoopRunner=0;iAsLoopRunner<arr.length;iAsLoopRunner++)
        {
            System.out.print(arr[iAsLoopRunner]+" "+"|"+" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    public static void print_string(String arr[])
    {
        for(iAsLoopRunner=0;iAsLoopRunner<arr.length;iAsLoopRunner++)
        {
            System.out.print(arr[iAsLoopRunner]+" "+"|"+" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    public static void print_double(double arr[])
    {
        for(iAsLoopRunner=0;iAsLoopRunner<arr.length;iAsLoopRunner++)
        {
            System.out.print(arr[iAsLoopRunner]+" "+"|"+" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    public static void print_long(long arr[])
    {
        for(iAsLoopRunner=0;iAsLoopRunner<arr.length;iAsLoopRunner++)
        {
            System.out.print(arr[iAsLoopRunner]+" "+"|"+" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    public static void print_vector(Vector arr)
    {
        for(iAsLoopRunner=0;iAsLoopRunner<arr.size();iAsLoopRunner++)
        {
            System.out.print(arr.get(iAsLoopRunner)+" "+"|"+" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    public static void sop(Object obj)
    {
        System.out.print(obj+" ");
    }
    public static void sopln(Object obj)
    {
        System.out.println(obj);
    }
    public static int[] getInt(int arraySize)
    {
        int arrayToReturn[]=new int[arraySize];
        for(iAsLoopRunner=0;iAsLoopRunner<arraySize;iAsLoopRunner++)
        {
            arrayToReturn[iAsLoopRunner]=takeInput.nextInt();
        }
        return arrayToReturn;
    }
    public static String[] getString(int arraySize)
    {
        String arrayToReturn[]=new String[arraySize];
        for(iAsLoopRunner=0;iAsLoopRunner<arraySize;iAsLoopRunner++)
        {
            arrayToReturn[iAsLoopRunner]=takeInput.next();
        }
        return arrayToReturn;
    }
    public static float[] getFloat(int arraySize)
    {
        float arrayToReturn[]=new float[arraySize];
        for(iAsLoopRunner=0;iAsLoopRunner<arraySize;iAsLoopRunner++)
        {
            arrayToReturn[iAsLoopRunner]=takeInput.nextFloat();
        }
        print_float(arrayToReturn);
        System.out.println("done ;)");
        return arrayToReturn;
    }
    public static long[] getLong(int arraySize)
    {
        long arrayToReturn[]=new long[arraySize];
        for(iAsLoopRunner=0;iAsLoopRunner<arraySize;iAsLoopRunner++)
        {
            arrayToReturn[iAsLoopRunner]=takeInput.nextLong();
        }
        print_long(arrayToReturn);
        System.out.println("done ;)");
        return arrayToReturn;
    }
    public static double[] getDouble(int arraySize)
    {
        double arrayToReturn[]=new double[arraySize];
        for(iAsLoopRunner=0;iAsLoopRunner<arraySize;iAsLoopRunner++)
        {
            arrayToReturn[iAsLoopRunner]=takeInput.nextDouble();
        }
        print_double(arrayToReturn);
        System.out.println("done ;)");
        return arrayToReturn;
    }
}
```

I want to add this class to java.util package as it facilitates in writing less code.Is it possible so that I can edit java.util package in my pc which reflects the changes in my pc alone ?

Comment: There is absolutely no need to. Put it in your own package, import from there.

Comment: You could just create that package in your application and put the class there - but why would you do that in the first place? Why not use a custom package? "it facilitates in writing less code" - what do you mean with that?

Comment: Btw, you _might_ want to thing about your naming. Classnames like `bk` don't tell much and don't adhere to the Java code conventions which state that class names should start with a captial letter (this will help you in the long run), method names normally don't contain underscores and instead of `double arr[]` I personally would write `double[] arr` since it's clearer that way that `arr` is the name and `double[]` is the type.

Comment: Another suggestion: instead of the deprecated `Vector` you might want to operate on `List` instances, best with some generic type.

Comment: I used to create so many projects so I want to make it somewhat like global.So I need not import the package into every project every time.

Comment: @Thomas I know its not good to use bk in lowarcase letters.I did it just because it looks simple and nothing other than that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `java.util` packaged is a core package of the Java language. 
Don't try to use it because first you could not (not allowed) and second it is a bad practice to couple the core classes with custom classes.

These are two distinct layers. Trying to mix them would very error prone for developers.
For example how to differ your util classes from jdk util classes ? How to handle conflicts if the JDK API is updated ?
Suppose you want to have two distinct versions of these util classes, with your solution you cannot either as all is in the JDK.
At last, it is clearly not a convention and usable solution with modern build tools as Maven or Gradle where you specify your dependent libraries.

You should rather add your abstraction classes in a custom package and create a specific library (JAR) if you want to reuse it in any project.

Comment: Please suggest me a way to use a single package any where in my pc without copy pasting the entire code in each and every project

Comment: As suggested, create a library : a jar that you include in all projects as you include JDK jars actually.

Comment: but that is almost same as including the package.It does't make much difference..:(

Comment: To compile yes but by introducing a library you distinct clearly which comes from the JDK and which comes from your classes and as said how to handle conflicts if the JDK API is updated ? If you use two distinct packages, you have not these problems. Suppose you want to have two distinct versions of these util classes, with your solution you cannot either.

Comment: @bharath there _is_ a huge difference: if you create one jar you have to pass around one file and can use all classes inside that jar. And if you want to move your projects to another machine you just have to move one file as well. If you're using a dependency manager like Maven (although Maven is more) you'll not even have to manually copy the file around, just upload it to a repository and let every project declare it as a dependency.

Comment: Thanks a lot people I would use maven for this

Comment: @Thomas We though the same thing. I have added it as example.